# What is the gun traverse limit of the 75mm armament on M3 Lee/Grant?

Tags: world-war-two, tanks

What is the gun traverse limit of the 75mm armament on M3 Lee/Grant?

http://www.onwar.com/weapons/tanks/firearms/fm3a4med.html and http://afvdb.50megs.com/usa/m3lee.html say 15 degree L/R.

Does anyone know of any direct and reliable source such as from US army archive records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [FM23-95 Basic Field Manual, 75mm Tank Gun M2 (Mounted in Medium Tank M3)](http://www.theshermantank.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/FM23-95-BFM-75mm-gun-M2-on-Lee.pdf), the amount of traverse to the left and the right, are actually 14° 0'. *Turns of hand wheel to traverse through maximum travel (28°)* is 25½. One turn of the hand wheel was 1° 6'.

Note that the link above is to a PDF which may download to your computer, but opens in Firefox directly in my own.

Comment: Did you check out John's link? That manual says 15 degree. Which reference should we trust?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm not a tanker, I was an electronics specialist. My gut feeling, and that is all it is, is that the 15deg number comes from what the turret/sponson that the 75 mm was mounted in/on/through could handle, but that the gun itself could only go 14. There is an M3 near me, but it's a locked up display piece.

Answer (score 11):

The operator's manual for the tank is available from [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Tm9-750MediumTanksM3M3a1AndM3a2). The OCR quality is not superb, but sufficient to confirm the 15 degree left and right traverse.

See page 41.